# How to delay few seconds before do something in Imacros?

Tags: imacros

I have this code:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:picker:ap:0
```

This macro above will wait for 6000 seconds for clicking OK button. Now, how to delay few seconds before OK button appear and then click it ?

Thank you !

Comment: This macro will wait maximum of 6000 seconds. As soon as the OK button appears it will click it. If the code that you pasted is ok buton. It will not wait 6000 seconds and then hit the code.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not exactly sure what you need, but to delay an action it's better to use WAIT rather than set a timeout

So in your case you'd have

```
WAIT SECONDS = 5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:picker:ap:0
```

you can also use WAIT with values of less than 1 second:

```
WAIT SECONDS = 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Endorse
WAIT SECONDS=5
```